# Predicate Problems For List Selection in C#

Tags: c#, .net, lambda, predicate

I have a curried typed-Lambda expression that I hoped would perform a selection and derive a unique element. Sadly there is a run-time exception.

Here is the code:

```
Entities relation = queryType(
            "test-instances",
            (new KeyValuePair<String, String>("cycle-id", testSetID))
        );

Entity target = (relation.entities.ToList<Entity>()).Find(
            //select entity with field 'name'
            e => (e.fields.Find(
                //and with non-epsillon value
                f => !(f.values.Find(
                    //of value 'targetValue'
                    v => (v.value.Equals(targetValue))
                ).value.Equals(""))
            )).name.Equals("name")
        );
```

The definition for `queryType()`:

```
       private Entities queryType(String entitiesType, params KeyValuePair<String, String>[] values)
    {
        addStandardHeaders();
        String query = parsePredicate(values);
        Task<HttpResponseMessage> filterTask = client.GetAsync(client.BaseAddress + RESTapi.ALMentitiesQuery(domain, project, entitiesType, query));
        Task.WaitAny(filterTask);
        //Callback:
        HttpResponseMessage result = filterTask.Result;
        if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            updateCookies(client.BaseAddress + RESTapi.ALMentitiesQuery(domain, project, entitiesType, query));
            mainHeaders.Clear();
            Task<Stream> output = result.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
            Task.WaitAny(output);
            //Callback:
            return (Entities)fromJSON(output.Result, typeof(Entities)); 
        }
        else
        {
            Exception exception = getException(result);
            throw new HttpException(exception.Title);
            return null;
        }
    }
```

The function `parsePredicate()` takes pairs () and encodes them into a predicate of a language the server understands.

The exception is that in the inner-most function; the bound-variable `v` is applied as `null`. `e` to `f` works though and the data-model I'm using is sound.

Any thoughts?

Here is the class for `Entities`:

```
public class Entities
{
    public List<Entity> entities{get;set;}

    public long totalResults{get;set;}

    public Entities(){entities = new List<Entity>();}
}


public class Entity
{
    public List<Field> fields { get; set; }

    public Entity() { fields = new List<Field>(); }
}

public class Field
{
    public String name { get; set; }


    public List<Value> values { get; set; }

    public Field() { values = new List<Value>(); }
}


public class Value
{
    public String value{get;set;}
}
```

Comment: It's hard to tell what's going on without a complete example. I'd personally use LINQ rather than List.Find, mind you...

Comment: @JonSkeet observe the ammendment; relation is of-type Entities

Comment: This still isn't a [mcve]. We can't reproduce the problem just from this. (Are you sure the problem isn't that `relation.entities.ToList()` is returning entities without the field values being filled in?)

Comment: @JonSkeet yes I'm sure. Would it be complete if I showed how relation is derived?

Comment: No, it would be complete if you provided us an example we could copy/paste/compile/run, with hard-coded data. It will then be minimal if you take all the irrelevant attributes off. We don't care about them, unless the problem is in how the data is fetched from the database - and you've just said you're sure that's not the case.

Comment: @JonSkeet I don't think I can do such a complete demonstration; but I think you could get a hypothesis out of this.

Comment: Why can't you provide a complete example? I don't see what's difficult about creating an example with hard-coded data (which doesn't have to be *real* data at all) and showing your code failing. It's very likely that as part of doing that diagnostic work, you'll find the answer yourself. (As an aside, I'd strongly encourage you to start following .NET naming conventions, too.)